# "I can't remember things as I used" — why not "as I used to"?

Tags: particles

There's a line in *Alice in Wonderland*:

> I can't remember things as I used—and I don't keep the same size for ten minutes together!

I wonder why the 'to' has been omitted from the verb 'used to'. Shouldn't the line read "I can't remember things as I used to—and I don't keep the same size for ten minutes together!"?

Comment: It *should* be *"used to"* in modern English usage. *Alice in Wonderland* was written in 1865, and they spoke slightly differently back then.

Comment: @PeterShor One does still hear people use the Lewis Carroll version, at least that's the case in Britain. It was far more common when I was a child in the late forties/early fifties.

Answer (score 2):

The normal contemporary use is "I can't remember things as I used to". I've not heard the Alice in Wonderland usage outside of the book.

Comment: Perhaps Alice just forgot to add the _to_.

Comment: Or the em dash is actually her abruptly cutting herself off.